# Styling KendoUI combo box

Tags: css, validation, styles, kendo-ui, kendo-combobox

I want to set style for required and invalid fields for KendoUI items (for example different background color for required input).

Style that I am using is here:

```
.k-textbox>input[required], 
.k-picker-wrap .k-input[required], 
.k-datepicker .k-input[required], 
.k-dropdown-wrap .k-input[required] {
   background-color: yellow;
}

.k-invalid {
   background-color: pink !important;
}
```

Here is jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/spuljko/wTev8/8/

DatePicker works OK, but I can't set style for required or invalid combo box.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
.k-input, input.k-textbox, textarea.k-textbox, input.k-textbox:hover, textarea.k-textbox:hover, .k-textbox > input{
background-color: yellow  !important;
}

.otherCombo .k-dropdown-wrap .k-input{
  background-color: blue !important;
}
```

Demo:http://jsbin.com/ivoqup/12/edit

Comment: It works, but it is not what I want. I am using MVC to build controlls, and rerquired tag is generated depending on data annotations. I can't place class on some combos, and not on others (well, I can, but then when required rule chnanges for some field there will be 2 places that needs to change). Also, there is other part, and that is client validation. Problem is that Kendo doesn't copy tags and styles to shadowed controls (required and k-invalid class).

Comment: That is not mention in your question. ok i am try.